# symfony2 QueryBuilder with a json field

Tags: symfony

Sorry for my english.
I'm blocked to a point and I wish you help me.
I have a json field in my entity. I want, with querybuilder, get statut of profil1.
Example from my field in my table in the BDD : (saved like this)

```
{
"Profil1":{
    "statut":"première visite",
    "site":"site officiel"
    },
"Profil2":{
    "statut":"ancien",
    "motif":"facebook"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    $queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('e')
            ->from('ACMEDemoBundle:YourEntity', 'e');
    $result = $queryBuilder
                    ->getQuery()->getResult();

    foreach ($result as $entity)
    {
        $jsonObject =  json_decode($entity->getJsonField()); //where jsonField is the name of the field containing the json
        $profile1Statut = $jsonObject['Profil1']['statut'];
    }
```

Probably you want to make some sanity checks also. And depending of the size of your table, it may be a little bit overkilling.

Comment: A little bit? Ii will make a fullscan.